# Can I make the class name to be a variable in python?

Tags: python, django

Can I make the class name to be a variable in the newer python release?

I mean can I short the following instructions to be briefer?

```
 if target == "course":
    return Course.objects.all()[start:end]`
 elif target == "Subject":
    return Subject.objects.all()[start:end]
 elif target == "Teacher":
    return Teacher.objects.all()[start:end]
```

to be briefer:

```
 return VARIABLE.objects.all()[start:end]
```

Comment: Class names already ARE variables - they just aren't ever reassigned in normal use.

Comment: Is this a Django app?

Comment: Thanks for everyone's answer. If it's not a Django app, Tim's answer is better. Otherwise, wim's ans looks better.

Comment: @wim Yes, it's a django code. But I expect to see a general solution, not only for Django. So I think both answers are good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like the Django ORM. If you're working in a Django application there is [a better way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model):

```
from django.apps import apps

Model = apps.get_model(app_label="myapp", model_name=target)
```

The `model_name` is case-insensitive. Here's a shortcut for the same thing:

```
Model = apps.get_model(f"myapp.{target}")
```

One big advantage here is that the model name is passed around as a string, so there will not be circular import problems due to imported model classes creating circular dependencies within your package, or app initialization problems due to model classes being imported too early.

The timing of model imports is sensitive in Django applications, as pointed out in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/applications/#how-applications-are-loaded):

> The application registry is initialized in three stages. At each stage, Django processes all applications in the order of [`INSTALLED_APPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-INSTALLED_APPS).
>
> First Django imports each item in [`INSTALLED_APPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-INSTALLED_APPS).
>
> If it’s an application configuration class, Django imports the root package of the application, defined by its [`name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.name) attribute. If it’s a Python package, Django looks for an application configuration in an `apps.py` submodule, or else creates a default application configuration.
>
> *At this stage, your code shouldn’t import any models!*
>
> In other words, your applications’ root packages and the modules that define your application configuration classes shouldn’t import any models, even indirectly.
>
> Strictly speaking, Django allows importing models once their application configuration is loaded. However, in order to avoid needless constraints on the order of [`INSTALLED_APPS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-INSTALLED_APPS), it’s strongly recommended not import any models at this stage.

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary:

```
classes = {
    'course': Course,
    'subject': Subject,
    'teacher': Teacher
}

...
    return classes[target].objects.all()[start:end]
```

Comment: It's smart and I can declare the class as a global variable for quick access.

Comment: I downvoted because this requires models to be imported, which can be problematic.